# Imported a .3ds model Can't append materials to it

Tags: materials, append

Why can't I append a material into a blend file that I imported a .3ds model into? It has a bunch of materials under the materials panel, but, since I am using cycles, none of them have anything other than the diffuse and material output.

I can create a new material and add nodes, but I can't append my favs!

There is no error. I click append, nav to the material, click append and nothing happens.

I am in blender 2.78c and on a mac. I have never had this happen before. And, I have been able to import and append in other files.

Here's the file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7wkt2vl5gpzgvy6/57%20chevy.blend?dl=0

Comment: What exactly do you expect should happen after pressing the *Append* button?

Comment: Well, traditionally, the material I append ends up in the materials panel and then I can apply it to a mesh, edit it and work with it. For this particular model, it doesn't even show up.

Comment: Just tested here appending some random materials and it worked fine, all materials show up with zero users and I can apply them to existing material slots with no problems.

Comment: Ah! Okay, so they don't show up in the materials window. But they do show up in the pull down menu! Okay, I didn't look deep enough. I just thought they would show up in the window. Thank you for your help!